# Small text, big image, don't want the next para beside it

Tags: html, css

I want :

```
---------------    Just a little bit    
| image is    |    of text.            
| taller than |
| text        |
---------------

Then comes            -------------- 
next para             | a pretty   |
with its              | picture    |
image                 --------------
```

but I am getting

```
---------------    Just a little bit    
| image is    |    of text.            
| taller than |    Then comes            -------------- 
| text        |    next para             | a pretty   |
---------------    with its              | picture    |
image                                    --------------
```

How to make it happen?

Comment: Can you post the HTML and CSS you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to give the second paragraph a CSS attribute `clear:both`. (Assuming that you're using floats to begin with.)

Comment: Yep, I was shooting with a shotgun, not knowing what his code looks like ;) .